# Subtracting sum of previous rows' data from current row's data in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, running-totals

I want to create a table or view in SSMS which should has a column called **qoh**. In that column should be calculate sum values of the column **rel_qty**. 
i.e.

1. The first data of **qoh** is the same of the first row's value of
   **rel_qty**.
2. Second value of **qoh** should be sum of first and second rows' value of
   **rel_qty**.
3. Third value of **qoh**  should be sum of first, second and third rows' value of **rel_qty**.

is there any possibilities to do this?

Here is my query. but this query satisfied only first and second rows not more that that,

```
SELECT  a.id, a.tot_qty, a.rel_qty, 
    (a.tot_qty - 
        COALESCE (a.rel_qty +
            (SELECT b.rel_qty
        FROM    dbo.foo AS b
        WHERE   (b.id = a.id - 1)), 
        a.rel_qty)
    ) AS qoh 
FROM    dbo.foo AS a
ORDER BY    a.id
```

And if my id skip one value this query failed to do the calculation. How can I fix this?

here is screenshot of my result

[image: click here to check the screenshot]

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64) 
 Jun 10 2015 03:35:45 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you need a running total.

If `tot_qty` is the same in all rows then you can use

```
SELECT  id, 
        tot_qty, 
        rel_qty, 
        tot_qty - SUM(rel_qty) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS qoh 
FROM dbo.foo
ORDER BY id;
```

`ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is the abbreviated version of `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

This window frame-ing option means that for each row the `SUM` will include itself and all predecessors as ordered by `id`.

The `ROWS` option is potentially important for efficiency as described in [Best approaches for running totals – updated for SQL Server 2012](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)